# Ubuntu cannot boot- ascpi exceptions

Tags: boot, 18.04, acpi

Ubuntu cannot boot and there are some ascpi exceptions and errors: 
Could not find NVP, problem loading uefi: db X.509 certificate and others.

Here are some information you may need:

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the kernel version is 4.15.0-47-generic. 
The BIOS version is 1.09 and I have an acer tmp256 mg laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Check for system updates, upgrades and fixing installs. Then delete the crash reports and reboot to see if the error stays there. Do you have a dual boot?

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -f
sudo rm /var/crash/*
sudo reboot
```